# Frama-c slice : choosing an entry to get pragma ctrl

Tags: frama-c

I'm having a problem getting a CTRL slice.

I'm trying to analyze OpenSSL by running this:

the code is like below

```
    int dtls1_process_heartbeat(SSL *s)

    {
    unsigned char *p = &s->s3->rrec.data[0], *pl;
    unsigned short hbtype;
    unsigned int payload;
    unsigned int padding = 16; /* Use minimum padding */
    /* Read type and payload length first */
    hbtype = *p++;
    n2s(p, payload);
    pl = p;

    if (s->msg_callback)
            s->msg_callback(0, s->version, TLS1_RT_HEARTBEAT,
                    &s->s3->rrec.data[0], s->s3->rrec.length,
                    s, s->msg_callback_arg);

    if (hbtype == TLS1_HB_REQUEST)
            {
            unsigned char *buffer, *bp;
            int r;

            /* Allocate memory for the response, size is 1 byte
             * message type, plus 2 bytes payload length, plus
             * payload, plus padding
             */
            buffer = OPENSSL_malloc(1 + 2 + payload + padding);
            bp = buffer;

            /* Enter response type, length and copy payload */
            *bp++ = TLS1_HB_RESPONSE;
            s2n(payload, bp);
            /*@ slice pragma stmt; */
            memcpy(bp, pl, payload);
            bp += payload;
            /* Random padding */
            RAND_pseudo_bytes(bp, padding);
            r = dtls1_write_bytes(s, TLS1_RT_HEARTBEAT, buffer, 3 + payload + padding);

            if (r >= 0 && s->msg_callback)
                    s->msg_callback(1, s->version, TLS1_RT_HEARTBEAT,
                            buffer, 3 + payload + padding,
                            s, s->msg_callback_arg);

            OPENSSL_free(buffer);

            if (r < 0)
                    return r;
            }
    else if (hbtype == TLS1_HB_RESPONSE)
            {
            unsigned int seq;

            /* We only send sequence numbers (2 bytes unsigned int),
             * and 16 random bytes, so we just try to read the
             * sequence number */
            n2s(pl, seq);

            if (payload == 18 && seq == s->tlsext_hb_seq)
                    {
                    dtls1_stop_timer(s);
                    s->tlsext_hb_seq++;
                    s->tlsext_hb_pending = 0;
                    }
            }

    return 0;
    }
```

`

```
frama-c ./ssl/d1_both.c -main dtls1_process_heartbeat -slice-calls memcpy -cpp-command "gcc -C -E -I ./include/ -I ./" -then-on 'Slicing export' -print
```

That produced nothing, so I then tried this:  want to get a backforward slicing

```
frama-c ./ssl/d1_both.c -main dtls1_process_heartbeat -slice-pragma dtls1_process_heartbeat -cpp-command "gcc -C -E -I ./include/ -I ./" -then-on 'Slicing export' -print
```

But I still get nothing like that

```
    void dtls1_process_heartbeat(void);

    void dtls1_process_heartbeat(void)
    {
      return;
    }
```

How can I get a slice like that?

```
function A (){
…

memcpy()
...

}


function B (){
…
…
...

}

function C (){
…

memcpy()

...

}
```

I want to capture everything to do with `memcpy()`, so I want to keep A and C, but not B.

How should I choose an entry point? How do I choose the pragma?

I hope I've stated my question clearly; it's had me confused for days.

Comment: Your question lacks a MCVE. You should preprocess `d1_both.c`, and post its contents somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that Frama-C Fluorine is an obsolete version. It has been released more than 3 years ago. Some slicing-related bugs have been fixed in the meantine. Please upgrade to a newer version, preferably [Aluminium](http://frama-c.com/download.html).

Second, the documentation for option `-slicing-value` is

> select the result of left-values v1,...,vn at the
>                       end of the function given as entry point (addresses are
>                       evaluated at the beginning of the function given as entry
>                       point)

It is unlikely to do what you want. Did you try option `-slice-calls`, more precisely `-slice-calls memcpy` ?

Also, keep in mind that `B` will be kept in the slice if it computes a value that is later used within a call to `memcpy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I updated frama-c to the latest veision But I still get the same problem@_@

Comment: And there is another Question, Once I chose memcpy in A as a entro point ;   If I slice successfully, only I get Is a backward slicing in A , but B and C will be deleted; what can I do to keep both A and C ?? even if A and C and B doesn't reference each other ??